# Trouble Understanding Associative Cache

Tags: caching, cpu-architecture, cpu-cache, microprocessors

I was reading a book on Cache Optimizations and in the Third Optimization ie *Higher Associativity to Reduce Miss Rate*
The author says

> 2:1 cache rule (for cache upto size 128KB) A direct-mapped cache of size N
> has the  same miss rate of 2-way associative cache of  size N /2.

But the author provides no explanation or proof to this and I am unable to understand this.
Could anyone explain how he came up with this rule?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's a "rule of thumb" that's (apparently) usually true for normal workloads, I'd guess from simulating traces of real workloads like SPECint and/or commercial software.  Not an actual *law* that's always true.

Seems reasonable if most of the misses are just conflict misses, not capacity misses.

Comment: ok so there isnt any proof or derivation for this rule right?

Comment: @SavannahMadison: Like I said, it's a "[rule of thumb](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rule_of_thumb)".  That English idiom means it's not true in every case, therefore not provable or derivable from first principles. The author is only claiming it's true for typical CPU workloads. As I said, though, it would follow from most misses being conflict misses, not capacity.

Comment: re: "Seems reasonable if most of the misses are just conflict misses, not capacity misses." wouldn't it be the otherway around? Adding assosiativity doesn't give you any help with capacity but does give you buffer with conflicts?

Comment: @Noah: Right, if most of the misses in a direct-mapped cache are from conflicts, adding associativity can avoid those misses, without introducing many new misses from reducing the capacity.

Comment: Guess I'm thinking about it the other way around. The surprising claim AFAICT is that direct-mapped can compete with associative caches which means most misses are capacity based. No?

Comment: @Noah: I see what you mean now.  If 2 accesses would map to the same set in a direct-mapped cache of size N/2, there's a good chance they'll map to different sets in a direct-mapped cache of size N.  (The normal assumption is that you double the number of sets, not the size of each line.)  And the extra capacity doesn't hurt. For an associative cache, LRU doesn't always make the perfect decision on which line to keep because it can't see the future, so two separate 1-way sets could occasionally be better.  Although more vulnerable to conflicts if there are other lines that alias both hot ones)

Comment: For doubling the number of sets to truly halve the number of conflict misses doesn't that require a random distribution of addresses? And even if assos 2 LRU isnt perfect, direct mapped in a sense is also LRU? It wouldn't really make sense if direct-mapped performed as well as assosiative and cpu makers still implemented assosiative because [CAM](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Content-addressable_memory) is so expensive. [This paper](http://pages.cs.wisc.edu/~markhill/papers/toc89_cpu_cache_associativity.pdf#page=14) has some hard numbers and it seems higher assos wins on conflict misses.

Comment: @Noah: I don't know how accurate this "rule" is.  It seems plausible that it's in the right ballpark.  Re: CAM: CPU cache is set-associative not fully-associative, not a full CAM.  Only 8 comparators for tags to be fetched into, regardless of how many sets.  So yes, it's more expensive, but the extra area and power for an associative cache is balanced by the area savings of only needing half the size for the main data to get a similar hit rate.